# Durable function template missing from function templates list

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I've created a web app and first durable function in it. Ran npm install durable-functions at the root of the directory of the app. But trying to create an orchestrator/second function app I see this warning in my portal. I do not see the durable function template in the list of azure function templates to create. How do I get this option back? Please help. Looks like I don't have the whole collection of extensions bundle. Where should this be installed?

[image]

This is what my host.config looks like. The extension bundle supported was 1* to 2.0 after running `npm install durable-functions` but I've updated it to 2* to 3.0 after reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register[image]

This is my package.json file
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated a new storage account and added application strings to my function app `AzureWebJobsStorage` and `AzureWebJobsDashboard` with value from the connection string for the new storage account. Restarted my function app.